# PHP script to copy a file from 1 FTP to another FTP

Tags: php, ftp, copy

I would like to copy a file (eg. MYFILE.csv) from **FTP 'SOURCE'** to **FTP 'TARGET'**. What type of command would you recommend for a **script in php**?

I have tried this but it didn't work.

```
<?php
$server = 'ftp.TARGET.com' ;//address of ftp server
$user_name = 'USER_TARGET'; // Username
$password = 'PASSWORD_TARGET'; // Password

$source = 'MYFILE.csv'; 
$dest = '/in/MYFILE.csv';
$mode='FTP_ASCII'; 

// set up basic connection
$connection = ftp_connect($server) ;

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($server, $user_name, $password);

// upload a file
if (ftp_put($connection, $dest, $source, $mode)) {
 echo "successfully uploaded $source\n";
} else {
 echo "There was a problem while uploading $source\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($connection);
?>
```

**=> The php script will be hosted in a folder on FTP A.
Thank you for your guidance.**

Comment: What didn't work? Which call failed? Any error message? Do you have an access to FTP server logs?

Comment: The FTP source and target are different servers, right? So actually the FTP source is an HTTP server, right?

Comment: The two servers are FTPs. I did not get an error message, I just ran it did not find the file in the target folder as expected ..

Comment: So the `ftp_put` returns true? No warning? What about the logs?

Comment: How do you run PHP script on FTP server?

Comment: Hi Martin,
Thank you for your help. 
So the error message I get is: "there was a problem while uploading home/inboxame/public_html/rb-onboarding/in/ftp_du_jour.csv"

Comment: I run from my browser because the script is in the public_html of my server provider. (ultimately I'll run a CRON: php name_of_my_script.php)

Comment: OK, so it is an HTTP server (it could be FTP server too, but that's irrelevant for this issue). As the `ftp_put` returns false (as you get to the "there was a problem" branch), it most likely issues a warning. Make sure you [enable error reporting in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), so that you an see the warning.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `file_put_contents`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

```
file_put_contents('ftp://user:pass@server/path/to/file.txt', $data);
```

It will return false on a failure:

```
if(file_put_contents('ftp://user:pass@server/path/to/file.txt', $data)) {
   // ftp upload successful
} else {
   // ftp upload failed
}
```

Why does your current method fail though?